# Update column based on data in same column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table OFFICE_HOURS which has data for working hours of a physician in an office(site). While loading this table from source system there were some issues and data were loaded incorrectly. 
 For a phy_id, site_id combination, the hours should be same (duplicates don't matter).
 So I need to update the table, so the hours in the first row of a phy_id,site_id combination should be used to update the rest of the rows which have same phy_id,site_id combination. 
Actual and expected results below. Please help.

[image]

Comment: `so the hours in the first row of a phy_id,site_id ...` how you know which one is the first row? is there any `row_id` or `date field`? right now both are exact the same

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter, any row should be fine. Just that for a phy_id, site_id combination, the hours should be same.

Comment: that doesnt make sense. How can both value be correct?

Comment: The thing is I just want the dataload to be success, its failing because of this issue. Since its an issue with the source, I can't say which one is correct data, just have to update it with some valid data to get through the data load.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont mind any hour

```
UPDATE OFFICE_HOURS o 
SET HOURS = (SELECT min(HOURS)
             FROM OFFICE_HOURS f 
             WHERE f.phy_id = o.phy_id
               and f.site_id = o.site_id
            )
```

If you want something more complex and with options to handle the hour selected.

```
with office as (
    SELECT *, 
           row_number() over (partition by phy_id, site_id order by hours) as rn
    FROM OFFICE_HOURS
)
UPDATE office o 
SET hours = (SELECT HOURS 
             FROM office f 
             WHERE f.phy_id = o.phy_id
               and f.site_id = o.site_id
               and f.row_id = 1
```

Comment: For the first query, Im getting this error SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification